# How to access Windows XAMPP localhost website using Python

Tags: windows, localhost, xampp, python

I'm using XAMPP on Windows to work on a new version of my website. I have modified the Windows hosts file and the XAMPP Apache httpd-vhosts.conf file so that my browsers access the version of the website that is in my XAMPP htdocs directory.
This works fine with my browsers but I want to use Python to access the site as well with code like with the following

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
webpage = "http://www.thedomain.org/index.html"
page = urlopen(webpage)
```

Running this code I get the following error:

> URLError: <urlopen error [WinError 10061] No connection could be made
> because the target machine actively refused it>

Any ideas on what configuration change(s) I need to make so that Python can access the local copy of my website just like it accesses websites normally? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, not an actual answer but rebooted and restarted XAMPP and the problem has vanished - at least for now. Unknown is whether or not this was a one-time event specific to my system and some sequence of events or not.